# Symfony action unable to retrieve proper AJAX JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, symfony

I am trying to send a JSON object into an Symfony action.

The script used to build and send the array looks like this:

```
var rows, arr = [];

    rows = table.find('table tbody tr');

    arr['x'] = new Array(rows.length);

    table.find('table tbody tr').each(function (i) {
        arr['x'][$(this).find('.username').text() - 1] = i;
    });

    console.log(arr); //PRINTS THE PROPER JSON OBJECT

    $.ajax('some/correct/path', {
        type: 'PUT',
        data: arr,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (e) {
           console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

And here I have an action for which should for now do nothing but capture the request data and send it back:

```
/**
 * @View\Route("/x", name="x", options={"expose"=true})
 * @View\Method("PUT")
 */
public function xAction(Request $request)
{

    $all = $request->request->all();

    return $this->json($all);
}
```

The problem here is that when I use the console.log on the `arr` variable, it results in a proper print, yet when I console log the `e` which was supposed to come from the action the result is:

> []

Here are the things I have already tried:

- Running the `$.ajax` with `data : 'sometext'` (response was: `{sometext: ""}`)
- Changing the method to **POST**
- Removing the `datatype: 'json'`
- Setting the data to: `JSON.stringify(arr)`
- Setting the data to: `{data : arr}`
- Setting the data to: `{data : JSON.stringify(arr)}`
- Setting the arr values directly into the array (without the `['x']` key)
- Clearing the cache
- Installing Linux
- Setting laptop on fire
- Going back in time to kill hitler

So far I have ran out of ideas to have it work properly.
What could be the issue here and how can I make it work?

Comment: Did you try with: `data: JSON.stringify(arr), contentType: "application/json"`?

Comment: Arrays have numeric index. You are creating an array like object as arr. Create object instead

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez same effect

Comment: @charlietfl This worked! Can you please post it as an answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` should be an object not array. Arrays only have numeric index and when you add the property `"x"` it becomes an *"array like"* object

Change

```
arr = [];
```

To

```
arr = {};
```